# Thymeleaf: #strings.equals with multiple values

Tags: thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf, how can you check multiple values with #strings.equals (is it possible?)?
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
${#strings.equals(firstName,['Yann'|| 'James'|| 'Harry'])}
```

Thanks !

Comment: What about Thymeleaf's [`#arrays`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#arrays) utility object. It has `${#arrays.contains(array, element)}` which you can use to "_Check if element or elements are contained in array_". (It depends on how you are able to create the array of names, in your specific situation.)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish using `#list.contains` rather than `#strings.equals`.

```
th:if="${#lists.contains({'Yann', 'James', 'Harry'}, firstName)}"
```